# Windows XP AutoPlay - Make all USB Devices behave the same way?

Tags: usb, windows-xp, autoplay

I set up event handlers and handlers within the registry to do a specific task I wanted. Then I set up the USB Autoplay settings to behave that way every time a device is inserted. I tried other USB storage devices and only the original one is behaving how I wanted, everything else has its own settings it seems and ignores the autoplay settings.  How can I set up AutoPlay settings that behave for all inserted flash drives or is that not possible on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

My experience, has been with XP Pro. (it may extend to other OS's, but I'm not sure)

I have come to realize, that when you go to the "properties" of each hard disk, the only way to set the autoplay to the way you want it (and make XP actually SAVE your settings), is to do each category of files individually (one-at-a-time), saying OK for each (then opening autoplay up again and going to the next category.

It's a real pain, when there are 6 things to set, but this seems to be the only way XP will "LOCK IN" the settings - it doesn't seen to want to work, if you change them all for each disk, THEN say OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the home version of Windows XP I believe you can use "gpedit.msc" (Group Policy Editor) to tweak your Autorun settings across the board.

*EDIT* I did a little bit of digging and [this blog post](http://www.lostintechnology.com/windows/how-to-change-autorun-settings-in-windows) (http://www.lostintechnology.com/windows/how-to-change-autorun-settings-in-windows) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Scratch that, I think you can only enable/disable Autorun/Autoplay with gpedit. If you could elaborate, meatyowllegs, what exactly is it you are trying to do with Autoplay?